# Is there a way to read packet information from a FIFO pipe into

Tags: c, pipe, fifo, libpcap

I've tried using something like

```
Fifo = open(<file path to my fifo>, "r");
pcap = pcap_fopen_offline(Fifo, errbuf);
```

But I got:
"unknown file format" as an error in my errbuf and pcap_fopen_offline returns NULL. Does anyone know a way around this or is there another way to make libpcap to function with libpcap?

Comment: pcap is for network interfaces, not pipes.

Comment: There are no packets in a pipe.

Comment: What are you expecting it to capture? A pipe is just a stream of bytes, there are no headers or packets. Maybe you meant to use a Unix-domain socket?

Comment: But I don't think pcap works with them, either. See https://superuser.com/questions/484671/can-i-monitor-a-local-unix-domain-socket-like-tcpdump

Comment: @Barmar  I currently have A FIFO pipe that typically is read by wireshark (sort of like this https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes), so it contains packet data in bytes. I'm currently trying to write a program that reads from that pipe instead so I can parse the data my way. I figured libpcap would be the way to do that.

Comment: It looks like it requires the file to be seekable, so it can check the file format and then rewind to the beginning to process it. PIpes aren't seekable.

Comment: `Fifo = open(<file path to my fifo>, "r");`?!?  That sure won't work.  Did you mean `Fifo = fopen(<file path to my fifo>, "r");`?

Answer (score 0):

From [man pcap_open_offline](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_fopen_offline)

> pcap_open_offline() is called to open a ''savefile'' for reading.
>
> fname specifies the name of the file to open. The file has the same format as those used by tcpdump(1) and tcpslice(1).
>
> Alternatively, you may call pcap_fopen_offline() to read dumped data from an existing open stream fp. Note that on Windows, that stream should be opened in binary mode.

Are you utilizing `tcpdump` data? Are you on windows (mode should be then "rb")?

p.s. you have a typo, shouldn't it be `fopen` instead of `open`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'll fix the typo. I currently have A FIFO pipe that typically is read by wireshark, so it contains packet data in bytes. I'm currently trying to write a program that reads from that pipe instead so I can parse the data my way.

Comment: Could it be a pcap - pcapng issue?

Comment: "Could it be a pcap - pcapng issue?"  Only with older versions of libpcap/WinPcap.  I wrote a small program to open a FIFO and then get a `pcap_t *` for it with `pcap_fopen_offline()`, and then use `pcap_loop()`, and it worked regardless of whether I used `cat` to write a pcap or pcapng file to the FIFO.